# How to use indexesOfObjectsPassingTest: in Swift

Tags: ios, closures, swift

The declaration of indexesOfObjectsPassingTest: looks like this in Swift,

```
func indexesOfObjectsPassingTest(predicate: ((AnyObject!, Int, CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool)!) -> NSIndexSet!
```

I've tried all sorts of permutations to get this to work, but I'm stumped, particularly with how you deal with this piece, `CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool)!`. I found it confusing enough, when I was first learning blocks in objective-c, how you translate from the declaration to actual use of a method, and the syntax of Swift is at least as confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code is working in the Playground for me ;) Hope it helps a bit

### Extra Function-Definition

```
import Cocoa

let list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

func test (object: AnyObject!, index: Int, stop: CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool
{
    let number = object as Int
    return (number % 2 == 0) //for even numbers
}

let result: NSIndexSet = (list as NSArray).indexesOfObjectsPassingTest(test)

println("\(result.lastIndex)") //prints "6" (because 8%2=0)
```

### Inline-Closure

I transformed my above example to work with an inline-closure (described in the Swift-eBook). The parameter-list and return-type is separated by the term `in`.

```
import Cocoa

let list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

let result: NSIndexSet = (list as NSArray).indexesOfObjectsPassingTest({
(object: AnyObject!, index: Int, stop: CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool in
    let number = object as Int
    return (number % 2 == 0) //for even numbers
})

println("\(result.lastIndex)") //prints "6" (because 8%2=0)
```

Comment: This works, but is there a way to do it inline? If I just replace "test" in indexesOfObjectsPassingTest with the way you defined test, it doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my example to work with an inline-closure. See the following chapter of the Swift-ebook for further explanation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html under the Sub-Heading "Closure Expression Syntax"

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got my head wrapped around it now. The code completion for this method, which works in objective-c to give you the syntax you need to use the method, doesn't give you the correct syntax in Swift. Hopefully, they will fix that in future releases.

Comment: Why do you have to cast list as NSArray as the receiver of the function?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like CMutablePointer was recently changed to UnsafeMutablePointer.

This one worked for me:

```
let indices = myArray.indexesOfObjectsPassingTest({
    (obj: AnyObject!, idx: Int, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool in
    var didPass = false
    //determine if obj passes test, if it does set didPass = true
    return didPass
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The block syntax is being replaced in Swift by a closure, the `predicate` parameter here.

So you can just do:

```
var array = NSArray(array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

var indexSet = array.indexesOfObjectsPassingTest({ (val: AnyObject!, index: Int, stop: CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool in return index > 2 })

indexSet.count
```

Out of the method, it could look like this:

```
var closure = {(val: AnyObject!, index: Int, stop: CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool? in
    /* Do Something */
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I get an error saying there needs to be a separator, and if I fix that per the compiler's suggestion, it gives me another error, and when I fix that one it gives me another error, etc.

Comment: You are right, my mistake! I am updating my answer to fit your needs.