# Get list of indexes using Array.filter instead of objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

is there any way to get list of filtered indexes instead of objects.

```
class Object
{
 var name
 var goal
}

var array<Object> = Array<Object>()

var filteredIndexes = array.filter{$0.name = "Sane"} // How to implement this?
```

Comment: `let indexes = array.enumerated().flatMap { (index, element) -> Int? in return element.name == "Sane" ? index: nil}`? Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225121/return-an-array-of-index-values-from-array-of-bool-where-true

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve your goal. For instance, you can filter `Array.indices` instead of the array itself.

Self contained example:

```
struct Object {
    let name:String
    let goal:String
}

let objects = [Object(name: "John", goal: "a"),Object(name: "Jane", goal: "a"),Object(name: "John", goal: "c"),Object(name: "Pete", goal: "d")]
let nameToBeFound = "John"
let filteredIndices = objects.indices.filter({objects[$0].name == nameToBeFound}) //[0,2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let animals = ["cat", "dog", "cat", "dog", "cat"]
let indexes = animals.enumerated().filter({ return $1 == "cat" }).map { return $0.offset }
print(indexes)
```

prints out `[0, 2, 4]`

Answer (score 1):

As [Lame said above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171482/get-list-of-indexes-using-array-filter-instead-of-objects/49172930#comment85348408_49171482), the solution from [Return an array of index values from array of Bool where true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225121/return-an-array-of-index-values-from-array-of-bool-where-true/38225167#38225167) can be adapted
to this case:

```
let filteredIndices = objects.enumerated().flatMap { $0.element.name == "Sane" ? $0.offset : nil }
```

One could also define a custom extension

```
extension Sequence {
    func indices(where predicate: (Element) -> Bool ) -> [Int] {
        return enumerated().flatMap { predicate($0.element) ? $0.offset : nil }
    }
}
```

which is then used as

```
let filteredIndices = objects.indices(where: { $0.name == "Sane" })
```

*Remark:* In Swift 4.1, this `flatMap()` method has been renamed to `compactMap()`